# Determine applicability of Google Docs viewer for external url

Tags: javascript, http, cross-domain, content-type

I am working on a CMS that allows users to define external document urls.  e.g. the following external url points to a PDF document:

http://xml.catmms.com/servlet/ImageServlet?imageId=C514418

although you can't tell that by looking at the url.

Some links will point to PDFs, others to simple web pages.  In the case of PDF documents I will use the Google Docs Viewer to display the content (the system must run on an iPad).

For straightforward images and web pages I won't use the Google viewer, but will just use an iframe.

In a client (Javascript) context, what is the simplest way for me to determine whether I need to use the Google Docs viewer, or a simple iframe?

The solution needs to work without encountering cross-site scripting issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Content-Type in the response header. In JS, you can do it like this :

```
// XHR stuff...
textResponse.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
```

Doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#section_9).

For PDF files, the Content-Type will be application/pdf.

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)